# Using a window function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

*I don't fully understand my problem to provide an intelligent title for this question, if anybody has a better idea, please edit!*

I have the following 14 records in an SQL Server database ([**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/521757)).

A stored procedure runs to get the total amount of time (`TimeEntryValue`) for each `ProjectId`, grouped by month.  This procedure works well until I add a new record with everything identical, aside from the `TimeEntryValue` and `PlanId`.

Plans are supposed to serve as overwrites to the values where `PlanId` is `null`.  This is also unfortunately where my stored procedure breaks, since it adds up the `5` and `10` value for January and February, giving me 15 where it should only be 5.

Here's the query the procedure runs:

```
DECLARE
    @projid int = 1279,
    @year int = 2015,
    @type varchar(20) = 'Projected',
    @plan int = NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT
        sum([Jan]) as [Jan], sum([Feb]) as [Feb], sum([Mar]) as [Mar],
        sum([Apr]) as [Apr], sum([May]) as [May], sum([Jun]) as [Jun],
        sum([Jul]) as [Jul], sum([Aug]) as [Aug], sum([Sep]) as [Sep],
        sum([Oct]) as [Oct], sum([Nov]) as [Nov], sum([Dec]) as [Dec]
    FROM
        (SELECT
            coalesce([Jan],0) as [Jan], coalesce([Feb],0) as [Feb], coalesce([Mar],0) as [Mar],
            coalesce([Apr],0) as [Apr], coalesce([May],0) as [May], coalesce([Jun],0) as [Jun],
            coalesce([Jul],0) as [Jul], coalesce([Aug],0) as [Aug], coalesce([Sep],0) as [Sep],
            coalesce([Oct],0) as [Oct], coalesce([Nov],0) as [Nov], coalesce([Dec],0) as [Dec]
        FROM 
            (SELECT
                t.TimeEntryValue,
                convert(char(3), datename(m,t.TimeEntryDate), 0) as ShortMonth
            FROM
                Project p
            JOIN
                TimeEntry t ON p.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
            WHERE 
                t.ProjectId = @projid
                AND t.TimeEntryType = @type
                AND YEAR(t.TimeEntryDate) = @year
                AND YEAR(p.ProjectStart) <= @year
                AND YEAR(p.ProjectEnd) >= @year
            ) p
        PIVOT
        (
            SUM (TimeEntryValue)
            FOR ShortMonth IN
                ( [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec] )
        ) AS pvt

        UNION ALL
        SELECT 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) result
END
```

`Projects` is just a small table to keep track of start/end times, and doesn't really affect the outcome of this particular query.

When run, this produces a result like this:

```
Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
15   15   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10
```

How can I have it return `5` for Jan and Feb, but `10` for the rest (where there is no override for `PlanId`?

#### Things I've tried

I've tried using `PARTITION` like so:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT TimeEntryId, TimeEntryValue, TimeEntryDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TimeEntryDate ORDER BY PlanId DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM TimeEntry
    WHERE ProjectId = 1279
        AND UserId = 403)
    AS a
    WHERE a.RowNumber = 1
```

This query works - it returns 12 rows, where the PlanId overrides are in the right place.  The trouble I'm having is implementing this in the procedure, and allowing to procedure to select individual PlanIds to look for (this uses all PlanIds).  I can't have window functions in the WHERE clause, so do I have to make yet another subquery for the procedure?  How could I even attack this?

Comment: Provide sample data as text, not as image.

Comment: better yet include your schema/data in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I'll get started on the sqlfiddle, thank you!

Comment: looks like your problem is with the data previous pivot? So maybe you can make a simple question with only that

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've added the SQLFiddle, thank you for suggesting that!  I can also close this question and re-ask it with just the simplified query, if that would be better.  I just wanted to avoid the "What are you trying to accomplish?" question.

Comment: I will take a look. And you can give this question sometime first. But as this article say [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Is better keep it simple

Comment: That is true, I'll keep that in mind for next time.  Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94106/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-scott-kaye).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CROSS APPLY can be used to limit a subselect to the "best" row:

```
select DISTINCT t1.ProjectId, t1.TimeEntryDate, t.TimeEntryType, t.TimeEntryValue from TimeEntry t1
  CROSS APPLY
   (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TimeEntry t2 WHERE t1.TimeEntryDate = t2.TimeEntryDate
    AND t1.TimeEntryType = t2.TimeEntryType
    AND (@plan is null OR t2.PlanId is NULL OR t2.PlanId = @plan)
    AND t1.ProjectId = t2.ProjectId AND t1.UserId = t2.UserId ORDER BY PlanId DESC) t
```

Now consider a CTE shrinking your TimeEntry table into the entries with the "best" planId:

```
with times as (
  select DISTINCT t1.ProjectId, t1.TimeEntryDate, t.TimeEntryType, t.TimeEntryValue from TimeEntry t1
  CROSS APPLY
   (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TimeEntry t2 WHERE t1.TimeEntryDate = t2.TimeEntryDate
    AND t1.TimeEntryType = t2.TimeEntryType
    AND (@plan is null OR t2.PlanId is NULL OR t2.PlanId = @plan)
    AND t1.ProjectId = t2.ProjectId AND t1.UserId = t2.UserId ORDER BY PlanId DESC) t
)
```

And then join `times` instead of `TimeEntry` in your procedure

resulting in something like this (I have no project table at hand - so might still contain things to fix):

```
DECLARE
    @projid int = 1279,
    @year int = 2015,
    @type varchar(20) = 'Projected',
    @plan int = NULL
BEGIN
    with times as (
      select DISTINCT t1.ProjectId, t1.TimeEntryDate, t.TimeEntryType, t.TimeEntryValue from TimeEntry t1
        CROSS APPLY
          (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TimeEntry t2 WHERE t1.TimeEntryDate = t2.TimeEntryDate
            AND t1.TimeEntryType = t2.TimeEntryType
            AND (@plan is null OR t2.PlanId is NULL OR t2.PlanId = @plan)
            AND t1.ProjectId = t2.ProjectId AND t1.UserId = t2.UserId ORDER BY PlanId DESC) t
         ) 
     SELECT
        sum([Jan]) as [Jan], sum([Feb]) as [Feb], sum([Mar]) as [Mar],
        sum([Apr]) as [Apr], sum([May]) as [May], sum([Jun]) as [Jun],
        sum([Jul]) as [Jul], sum([Aug]) as [Aug], sum([Sep]) as [Sep],
        sum([Oct]) as [Oct], sum([Nov]) as [Nov], sum([Dec]) as [Dec]
    FROM
        (SELECT
            coalesce([Jan],0) as [Jan], coalesce([Feb],0) as [Feb], coalesce([Mar],0) as [Mar],
            coalesce([Apr],0) as [Apr], coalesce([May],0) as [May], coalesce([Jun],0) as [Jun],
            coalesce([Jul],0) as [Jul], coalesce([Aug],0) as [Aug], coalesce([Sep],0) as [Sep],
            coalesce([Oct],0) as [Oct], coalesce([Nov],0) as [Nov], coalesce([Dec],0) as [Dec]
        FROM 
            (SELECT
                t.TimeEntryValue,
                convert(char(3), datename(m,t.TimeEntryDate), 0) as ShortMonth
            FROM
                Project p
            JOIN
                times t ON p.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
            WHERE 
                t.ProjectId = @projid
                AND t.TimeEntryType = @type
                AND YEAR(t.TimeEntryDate) = @year
                AND YEAR(p.ProjectStart) <= @year
                AND YEAR(p.ProjectEnd) >= @year
            ) p
        PIVOT
        (
            SUM (TimeEntryValue)
            FOR ShortMonth IN
                ( [Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec] )
        ) AS pvt

        UNION ALL
        SELECT 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) result
END
```

Just tested on your fiddle with SQL-Server selected - produces 5,5,10,10,10,10...

Edit:

```
This would be the correct query for the @plan dependency discussed in comments:

AND (
    (@plan is null AND t2.PlanId is NULL) OR 
    (@plan is not null AND (t2.PlanId IS NULL OR t2.PlanId = @plan))
)
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, I had no idea `CROSS APPLY` even existed!  Is there any way to have the `@plan` parameter work inside the apply?  I tried naievly adding an `AND t1.PlanId = @plan` (also tried with `t2`), but I only get zeroes after that.

Comment: No problem, you've gotten farther than I ever did with this!  If it's `NULL`, it should return all the defaults (`10` for each month), but if it's `1`, it should return `5, 5, 10, 10, 10...`  Hopefully this doesn't change things too much!

Comment: Legendary, I can't thank you enough.  I can just pass `-1` to `@plan` to get the defaults, which actually takes a step off the server backend.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Change this to use group by:

```
SELECT
            t.TimeEntryValue,
            convert(char(3), datename(m,t.TimeEntryDate), 0) as ShortMonth
        FROM
            Project p
        JOIN
            TimeEntry t ON p.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
        WHERE 
            t.ProjectId = @projid
            AND t.TimeEntryType = @type
            AND YEAR(t.TimeEntryDate) = @year
            AND YEAR(p.ProjectStart) <= @year
            AND YEAR(p.ProjectEnd) >= @year
```

like this

```
        SELECT
            SUM(t.TimeEntryValue) TimeEntryValue,
            convert(char(3), datename(m,t.TimeEntryDate), 0) as ShortMonth
        FROM
            Project p
        JOIN
            TimeEntry t ON p.ProjectId = t.ProjectId
        WHERE 
            t.ProjectId = @projid
            AND t.TimeEntryType = @type
            AND YEAR(t.TimeEntryDate) = @year
            AND YEAR(p.ProjectStart) <= @year
            AND YEAR(p.ProjectEnd) >= @year
        GROUP BY
            convert(char(3), datename(m,t.TimeEntryDate), 0)
```

The sql part above this code expects one record for Jan/Feb etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, even with a query such as `SELECT SUM(TimeEntryValue) TimeEntryValue FROM TimeEntry WHERE ProjectId = 1279 GROUP BY TimeEntryDate` on the SQLFiddle.  I'm looking for `5 5 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10`  Thank you though!